# How to Bind DataTable to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to bind DataTable to DataGridView as below;

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (ConsumerProduct c in ctx.ConsumerProducts)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = c.ID;
    row["Model"] = c.Model;
    row["Status"] = "Offline";

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

I get exception at the first line itself `row["Id"]`

> Column 'Id' does not belong to table .

**P.S.** I have already added these columns in the designer view of dataGridView.

Comment: @Bharadwaj, Please review tag I am talking about WinForm not Asp.Net

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just created a blank `DataTable` and then you are trying to add data to particular columns like `Id`, `Model` and `Status`.

You have to add those columns as well.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id");
table.Columns.Add("Model");
table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string)); //with type
```

There is no issue in biding.

Also you can project your required column to an Anonymous type and then bind that to your data grid like:

```
var result = ctx.ConsumerProducts
                .Select(r=> new 
                {
                    Id = r.ID, 
                    Model = r.Model,
                    Status = "Offline"
                }).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added my columns in designer view. Do I still need to add again? DataTable?

Comment: @Abhijeet, yes your `DataTable` doesn't have any knowledge of your Grid columns, so you have to add the columns in DataTable. You can also try `table.Rows.Add(c.ID, c.Model, "Offline");` this will add the  rows with data, but not really sure if binding would work in that way.

Comment: I miss-out the formatting of the columns this way :-(

Comment: @Abhijeet, so add the columns in `DataTable`, that is the preferred way as well. By the way, why you can't use LINQ to do this, you will not need the `DataTable` in that case.